# OpenCV: Library not loaded: libjpeg.8.dylib

Tags: node.js, macos, opencv, jpeg, homebrew

This error with OpenCV (I'm trying to use Node + OpenCV - as in [node-opencv](https://github.com/peterbraden/node-opencv)) has been driving me crazy. I've looked at many answers on StackOverflow or otherwise, and I think this could be a problem with the upgraded Homebrew or maybe with OpenCV. Unless it is a problem with the way I imported OpenCV.

Does anyone understand this/know what to do?

```
module.js:598
  return process.dlopen(module, path._makeLong(filename));
                 ^
Error: dlopen(/Users/Joe/SRS/node_modules/opencv/build/opencv/v6.0.0/Release/node-v51-darw
in-x64/opencv.node, 1): Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/jpeg/lib/libjpeg.8.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/opt/opencv/lib/libopencv_highgui.2.4.dylib
  Reason: image not found
    at Object.Module._extensions..node (module.js:598:18)
    at Module.load (module.js:488:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:447:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:439:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:498:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/Joe/SRS/node_modules/opencv/lib/bindings.js:4:15)
    at Module._compile (module.js:571:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:488:32)
```

Comment: Looks like libjpeg is not properly installed - or a different version. Check if `/usr/local/opt/jpeg/lib/libjpeg.8.dylib` exits. Maybe you need to manually install jpeg/libjpef via brew.

Comment: So I just checked - `libjpeg.9.dylib` exists, but not `libjpeg.8.dylib`. I tried manually installing using `brew install libjpeg`, but exact same error persists.

Comment: For some reason, I think [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/385225/libjpeg-8-dylib-reference-broken-after-brew-upgrade) is a related issue. Do you think I should try `brew install libjpeg.8.dylib`?

Comment: So jpeg has been updated to a newer version than opencv was build with. Maybe brew will update their opencv build at some point where a reinstall would solve the issue. Or you try to rebuild opencv by yourself with `brew reinstall --build-from-source opencv`

Comment: Wait so if I reinstall and build from source, is that going to have nasty repercussions for the rest of the environment? Sorry if my questions seem amateur - I haven't worked with OpenCV in the past. Would it be easier for me to downgrade the jpeg, so to speak?

Comment: And is `brew reinstall --build-from-source opencv` the only command I will need to run?

Comment: Shouldn't have any other impact. Then again changing things may always have an impact - see your jpeg brew upgrade. Building from source just means spending time compiling your own version instead of installing brew's pre build binaries. Nothing more than that one command is needed - if it runs successfully. You may want to try with out the `--build-from-source` to see if an updated binary is getting installed - but I would assume they bump their minor version number so this would happen automatically..

Comment: They just released a new (minor?) version of OpenCV - I found out without the `--build-from-source`. Thanks a ton for your help.

Comment: I just built from source, not working, truly frustrating

Comment: @diek just uninstalling and reinstalling worked for me

Comment: I will try again. What is most annoying I am not sure why this is coming up. I am not using OpenCV directly, something is linked.... I'm using Django and TastyPie, and makemigrations is failing because of this.

Comment: I had to do a:
brew upgrade
brew uninstall --force gdal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was getting the same error and reinstalling Open CV fixed it. I ran 
 brew reinstall --build-from-source opencv.